# What is tag [tag:cpu-cache] for?

Tags: discussion, tags

*Caches* appears at many different levels or places in computer system. You can have on-chip caches, sytem caches and network caches. But the only tag about caches is apparently the tag [cpu-cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache), which seems very restrictive.  Is that intentional, and why? Why not just [cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cache)?

Answer (score 4):

The tag [cpu-cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache) is about caches in computer architecture and their relevance to programming. It so happens that we have many questions on that topic, mostly about CPU/memory architecture and about algorithm design.

The tag is definitely not too restrictive — if anything, it's overloaded, as the relevance of CPU caches to algorithm speed and the architecture of memory subsystems are very different topics. Other tags (e.g. [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) or [computer-architecture](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) serve to distinguish these topics.

[caching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching) would be a useful tag for a question about the design of caches. I can't find any.

[caching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching) and [cpu-cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache) are very different topics. The two tags could coexist, on a question about memory subsystem design (as opposed to what we have in the [computer-architecture](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) [cpu-cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache), which is about analysis of existing designs); there is not much correlation between their domains.

Comment: Can you give an example of a [tag:caching] question that is computer science, but not about [tag:cpu-cache] in the broader sense that babou proposes?

Comment: @Raphael Something about caching in network protocols, is the obvious example that comes to mind. And in the other directions, most [tag:cpu-cache] are not really about caching, or about a very specific aspect of it.

Comment: It seems that we could indeed potentially use both [tag:caching] and [tag:cpu-cache] with an overlap in questions that deal specifically with the impact (the design of) CPU caches on algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason against that; as far as I know, the term *caching* is not overloaded (with similarly popular notions). Also, as far as computer *science* is concerned, we probably don't care where exactly the cache resides.

If we change the tag it shouldd probably be [caches](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caches) to go with our convention of using the plural, or alternatively [caching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching). I'd associate the former more with "How does a cache work?" and the latter with "How do I analyse this algorithm considering caching?" but that may be my personal bias.

Comment: [tag:caches] or [tag:caching] do not make much difference since tags
are intended to be used as approximations. I tend to like
[tag:caching] better since it emphasize the effect rather than a
specific device to achieve it. But not worth a fight or even a
disussion.  How do we go about changing this?

Comment: [tag:caching] (or [tag:caches], I'm indifferent) is not at all the same topic(s) as [tag:cpu-cache].

Comment: @babou We wait a couple of days for more opinions to trickle in. If there is a consensus, we can mod-hammer the thing; in the meantime, you can [suggest a synonym](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/cpu-cache/synonyms) yourself; if it collects enough votes, it will be enacted independent of the discussion. A proper tag merge (which removes the old one), however, requires moderator action and thus, arguably, some result here.

Comment: @Gilles: Is it a superset? That would be okay then, I guess.

Comment: Calling [tag:cpu-cache] a subset of [tag:caching] sounds like calling [tag:regular-languages] a subset of [tag:computation-models].